# How can I import .cvs files with a loop in R?

Tags: r, loops, csv, for-loop

I've got a series of .cvs files called `Natalidad[i]`, where `[i]` is the year of the data from 1996 to 2020. I want to make I loop in order to load each of them. I've tried the next code, but it is working.

```
for (i in 1996:2020) { 
  nacimientos[i] <- read.csv("Natalidad [i]_p.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ";") 
}
```

I've also tried without `[]` and substituting with `()`.
My question might be basic. I'm not familiarized with loops in R, so there's probably something essential that I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do this in R, you have to paste the string of the file name first. R cannot have variables inside a string. E.g. `paste0("first part", i, "second part")`, where i is the variable.

Try

```
for (i in 1996:2020) { 
  nacimientos[i] <- read.csv(paste0("Natalidad ", [i], "_p.csv"), header = TRUE, sep = ";") 
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That was really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

As you originally tagged the question as Python, it could be done as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

nacimientos = [pd.read_csv(f"Natalidad [{year}]_p.csv", sep=";") for year in range(1996, 2021)]
```

This creates a list of dataframes with the first being for 1996. It uses a Python "list comprehension" to build the list.

This would be equivalent to:

```
nacimientos = []

for year in range(1996, 2021):
    df = pd.read_csv(f"Natalidad [{year}]_p.csv", sep=";")
    nacimientos.append(df)
```

Comment: Even though it's correct and compact I think it (list comprehension) is not as easily understandable to a Python begginer as a simple `for` loop would be.

Comment: Sorry, I was looking for advice in R. I'm very much a begginer here, I forgot to clarify. Thank you anyways, your answer may be useful.